# CakePHP: findByEmail() function returns an array

Tags: cakephp, syntax

I have a database table Users with an id column "uid" and an email column "email".  I am executing this line of code:

```
$user = $this->User->findByEmail($this->data['User']['email']);
```

Where `$this->data['User']['email']` is unquestionably returning the correct email address and this email address is in the database table.  However, the result of:

`echo "User is :" . $user` = User is: Array

I need to know how to get the value of the id out of this array.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Cake always returns an associative array by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$user[0]` or `print_r($user)`

Comment: Thanks.  print_r showed me the internal structure and I got the value with the correct indexing -- which was $user['User']['UID'].